# Is there any good and simple plugin for PHP to compress JS?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to compress my JS files automatically with PHP. I tried to find the best plugin for this in many search engines and forms. Everyone suggests the Minify plugin. But this plugin is very large. So, I want a simple and reliable plugin to compress JS files.

Please help me.

I want a plugin like this:

```
<?PHP
  include_once "js_compress.php";
  $file = "http://www.example.com/src/page_optimize.js";
  $data = file_get_contents($file);
  echo js_compress($data);
?>
```

Comment: Hi dda! thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use YUI Compressor. I have done similar thing using php.But to do so you have to create a php file with exec command which will run a command of YUI.

So first download their plugin from here : http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Then create a php and put the jar file in the same folder when your php is placed.

But first create a exec string in php like below :

exec("java -jar compiler.jar --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS --js  --js_output_file ");

This will execute the command and compress your js.

For more than 1 files loop the same exec sentence over the input directory and fetch js 1 by 1.

I hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want basic minimization, you can just parse the js and remove any line breaks. If you want full minimization, I couldn't find any library for it, but I did find a guide using google's closure API http://www.sitepoint.com/compress-javascript-with-php/